# Trying to replicate descriptive statistics analysis tools excel in python / add mode to describe() function

Tags: python, statistics, summary

Im trying to replicate descriptive statistics (summary statistics) analysis tool in excel with python (jupyter notebook) by aggregating some of descriptive statistics availbale in pandas library, but everytime i add mode function in the code, it always return :

> ValueError: cannot combine transform and aggregation operations

my code is :

```
df2 = df[["pm10","so2", "co", "o3", "no2" ]]
df2.agg(
    {
        "pm10": ["mean", "sem", "median", "std", "var", "kurt", "skew", "min", "max", "sum", "count", "mode"],
        "so2": ["mean", "sem", "median", "std", "var", "kurt", "skew", "min", "max", "sum", "count", "mode"],
        "co": ["mean", "sem", "median", "std", "var", "kurt", "skew", "min", "max", "sum", "count", "mode"],
        "o3": ["mean", "sem", "median", "std", "var", "kurt", "skew", "min", "max", "sum", "count", "mode"],
        "no2": ["mean", "sem", "median", "std", "var", "kurt", "skew", "min", "max", "sum", "count", "mode"]
    }
  )
```

it only return error when icluding mode function, the other function work well. thi is my [dataset](https://data.jakarta.go.id/dataset/dd749a07-d36d-4f13-9e86-7d0a84bb90f3/resource/dd5b5b60bfba593c41e8615269d9d221/download/Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-SPKU-Bulan-Juli-Tahun-2020.csv)

the result that i want :
[image: i want mode to be aggregated]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using mode function from statistics package:

```
from statistics import mode
func_list = ["mean", "sem", "median", "std", "var", "kurt", "skew", "min", "max", "sum", "count", mode]
df2.agg(
{
    "pm10": func_list,
    "so2": func_list,
    "co": func_list,
    "o3": func_list,
    "no2": func_list
})
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, i already solved the problem by doing append and concat to the describe() function, but your answer is helpful too

Answer (score 0):

its not the cleanest way to do this but it works, im also adding some other measures like nans value and range

```
df2 = df[["pm10","so2", "co", "o3", "no2" ]]      
                                                  
def describe(df2, stats):
    d = df2.describe()
    return d.append(df2.reindex(d.columns, axis = 1).agg(stats))

df2_desc = describe(df2, ["median", "var", "sem", "kurt", "skew", "sum",])

count_nan = df2.isnull().sum(axis=0) 
df2_append = df2_desc.append(pd.Series(count_nan, name='nans'))

df_mode = df2.mode(axis=0, numeric_only=True, dropna=True)
df2_concat = pd.concat([df2_append, df_mode])                             
df2_concat.loc['range'] = df2_concat.loc['max'] - df2_concat.loc['min']
df2_concat
```